# Approach on R's quadprog constraint variables in efficient portfolio theory application

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am trying to use quadprog in R to find the best portfolio among 15 assets

I compiled historical returns and the objective is to minimize variance such that target return is 0.0125 with 3-5 assets

Excel Solver couldn't find a solution so I’m trying with R. The problem is that I am not extremely familiar with the syntax of setting up the constraints, solve.QP() is returning negative weights for some, and allocating among all 15 assets.

Is there a way to add constraint:

1. No negative weights
2. Use at least 3 and at most 5 assets?

This is my code:

```
library(quadprog)
returns = read.csv("~/Desktop/varcovar.csv",1)
attach(returns)

muv = c(0.009579072,0.001579566,0.00888999,0.016570647,0.007224933,0.005135062,0.009640062,0.005987327,0.010814888,0.000308419,0.005335805,-0.022758801,0.00170418,0.009307576,0.008512812)

sigmatrix = matrix(cov(returns),15,15,1)

targmu = 0.0125

Dmat = 2*sigmatrix
dvec = numeric(15)
Amat = matrix(c(rep(1, 15), muv),15,2)
bvec = c(1,targmu)
solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq = 1)
```

I can relax the target return if needed, but I want to at least see which assets quadprog is tending to choose

I tried adding a lower bound of 0

```
lb = rep(0, num_assets)
```

and I get "Error in if (res1$ierr == 1) stop("constraints are inconsistent, no solution!") else if (res1$ierr ==  :
the condition has length > 1"

Chatgpt gets very confused with  Amat definition and doesn't seen to help much